# How to copy a node by using Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to copy a node by using cypher. Now I can get all properties by `properties()` function in cypher, what is the next step? Do I have to using the driver like `py2neo` to write them in python. Dose Cypher has some function like `copy()` to copy the node directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the simplest answer:

```
match (old:Mynode) create (new:Mynode) set new = old
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it really works. And it is really simple. By the way, is there any simple way to copy a sub-graph in neo4j(e.g. I want to copy old Node and the nodes within one degree and the relationships between them to the new sub-graph)?

Comment: fyi: redisgraph does not support it yet

Answer (score 7):

call apoc cloneNodes :)

```
MATCH (f:Foo{name:'Foo'}),(b:Bar{name:'Bar'}) WITH f,b CALL
apoc.refactor.cloneNodes([f,b]) yield input, output RETURN *
```

you can read all about it and the awsomeness power of apoc [here](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index33.html#_clone_nodes)

Comment: Thx, apoc really awesome, your answer is also perfect.